# Calculate Distance between two Coordinates and display it inside an Label of an UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, geocoding, cllocationmanager

I am trying to calculate the distance between two Coordinates and showing them inside an Label of an UITableViewCell.

So far so good - my problem now is, that every time I scroll the tableview, the value of the label gets changed and the distances get completely mixed up...
What I've read so far is, that this problem gets created due dequeuing and reusable data

But before I speak any further, this is my code:

```
class JobTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!

let location = CLLocationManager()
static var takenLocation: String?

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    location.delegate = self
    self.location.startUpdatingLocation()
}

    
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        //get job coordinates
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(job.location) { placemarks, error in
            let placemarkW = placemarks?.first
            if let placemark = placemarkW
            {
                let lat = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let lon = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let jobLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!)
                //get user coordinates
                let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                //get distance between coordinates
                let distance = myLocation.distance(from: jobLocation) / 1000
                self.distance.text = String(format: "%.01fkm", distance)
                self.job.distance = distance
                //JobTableViewCell.takenLocation = String(format: "%.01km", distance)
            } else {
                self.distance.text = "Not Valid"
                self.job.distance = 0.0

            }
            self.reloading?.reloadIt()
        }
    }
    self.location.stopUpdatingLocation()
    guard let _: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
}
```

}

I don't have any trouble calculating or showing the distance, my only problem is that I don't know how to reuse the LabelData(if this is even the correct approach :/ )

As far as I know, I need to go over to the TableViewController and write something like **cell.distance.text = idonwknowwhat**, but that's the point where I stuck

UPDATE:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JobCell", for: indexPath) as! JobTableViewCell
    let job = jobs[indexPath.row]
    cell.job = job
    cell.jobHeader.text = job.postHeader //just leave this line so the function is not empty 


    //cell.cellDelegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Comment: `self.location.startUpdatingLocation()` in layoutSubViews is a terrible idea you are aware that it gets called multiple times dont you? also is your `JobTableViewCell` being reused in your tableView? Are there multiple cells which shows distance? if yes how do you pass latlong to these cells to which you calculate distance from current location? also if there are multiple cells calculating distance, all of them must be independently calling `startUpdatingLocation` multiple times, thats messed up ! what are u trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, every single Cell of the tableView shows an distance - each cell is a job with its own location... and I don't pass latlong anywhere, I just calucalte it inside the locationManager function... how to I do it that not every single cell calls startUpdatingLocation? And yes, the JobTableViewCell is being reused in my tableview, ill update my question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues here.

1. It's not terribly important, but the process of getting a placemark, finding the location, getting latitude and longitude, and building a new location is unnecessarily convoluted. The `CLPlaceMark` array returned from `geocodeAddressString` has a `location` which is the `CLLocation`, so just use that directly:

   ```
   geocoder.geocodeAddressString(job.location) { placemarks, error in
       guard
           let jobLocation = placemarks?.first(where: { $0.location != nil })?.location
       else {
           // handle error where no placemark with a valid location was found
           return
       }

       // get distance between coordinates

       let distance = myLocation.distance(from: jobLocation) / 1000

       // now update model or UI here
   }
   ```

   Likewise, the `didUpdateLocations` is giving you an array of `CLLocation` objects, so getting the last valid location (i.e. where `horizontalAccuracy` is non-negative) is one line of code:

   ```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       guard
           let myLocation = locations.last(where: { $0.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 }) 
       else { return }

       // now just use `myLocation`
   }
   ```
2. The geocoding of the `job.location` does not belong in the `didUpdateLocations`.

   If your current location updates, do you really need to geocode the job’s location again? (I know you appear to be canceling the location updating, but it suggests a general conflation of the logic of the user’s location and the geocoding process.)

   Furthermore, I would suggest that the `Job` object should not have a `distance` property, but rather just a `coordinate` property that is the `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. The coordinates are a property of the job, not the distance from where you happen to be at that moment. The `CLLocationDistance` of the job to the user’s current location should be calculated as cells are displayed and updated.

   The virtue of decoupling the location updates from the geocoding is that you can easily, for example, keep the location updating if you want. Obviously, if you are only showing distances to the nearest tenth of a kilometer, you might add a `distanceFilter` of 100 meters, to reduce the amount of unnecessary work being performed.
3. You have made the `CLLocationManager` a property of the cell (given that your delegate method is updating cell properties). The manager should not be a property of the cell. You really only need/want a single `CLLocationManager` for the entire view (or possibly the entire app).
4. You are updating cell properties inside an asynchronous completion handler closure. You need to be very careful, because you do not know if the cell has been reused by the time the closure finishes. If you do asynchronously want to update a cell, you should requery the model collection to get the updated row.

So, pulling this all together, I would suggest:

- Change the `Job` model to capture the coordinates, not the distance;
- When cell is to be shown, geocode the address if needed (saving the coordinates in the model to save needing to perform redundant geocoding requests);
- Have a single `CLLocationManager` instance, just reloading the table when the location changes.

See https://github.com/robertmryan/GeocoderTableView.git for example.

Comment: Bro I honestly don't know how to thank you - you put so much effort in this - not only that I got my problem solved, I also understood (after some time) my problem and your solution :) I know that this doesn't belong to my original question(and I might open another post for this) but is there now a way to sort the jobs by the distance? My approach would be to just use a sorting function like **self.jobs.sort(by: {$0.distance < $1.distance})**  but this won't work as the VC first needs to calculate the distances before sorting anything, or am I wrong? Because right now, the VC only  1/2

Comment: 2/2 calculates as soon as I'm scrolling, so how should it sort the cells before calculating all the distances

Comment: @SwiftyJason - The sorting is not the problem. The issue is that one should geocode as needed in the UI. But sorting means geocoding all records. The problem is that Apple rate-limits the geocoding. So if you have 5 jobs, it's a non-issue. But if you have hundreds, that starts to become an issue and your geocode requests will start failing. The question is whether you can geocode the job listings before the app retrieves them (e.g. either server side or as they're posted). That would be far more efficient, anyway. Then sorting by distance is trivial exercise.

Comment: This sounds like something to discover in my free time haha - but thank you for this as well, now I got a better understanding of what I even need to do - enjoy your weekend

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

As Sandeep said in their comment, calling `self.location.startUpdatingLocation()` in layoutSubviews is a bad idea. Do that in `viewDidLoad()`, or maybe `viewDidAppear()`.

Next point: Your completion handler for your call to `geocodeAddressString(_:completionHandler:)` gets the user's current location and calculates a new distance value. You then store that into the text of a label view, `distance`. Presumably this is a label that is not part of a table view cell.

What you should do is to save the distance value (as a Double) to an instance variable in your view controller, and then tell your table view to reload any cells that display distance information. If that is a single cell, you can call `reloadRows(at:with:)` with a single indexPath. If it's multiple, but not all, cells, you can pass in an array of IndexPaths for the cells to update. If you need to update all the cells in your table view, call `reloadData()`.

Your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` table view delegate method should be written to take the distance value from your instance variable and install it in those cells that need it.